# RegEx Pattern Matcher with multiple space word

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a `String` into two sub-strings as follows:

```
String value = "Verify Payment 2";
```

With the two parts expected to be:

```
String one = Verify Payment
String two = 2
```

I'm using the split function (split by space) but it gives a result with 3 Strings:

```
String[] output = eachElement.getText().split("\\s");
```

Comment: More example input please.

Comment: agree, give some more complex examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String s= "Verify Payment 2";

    Pattern p =Pattern.compile("(.+)\\s(\\w+)");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()){
        System.out.println("String 1 ="+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("String 2 ="+m.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: what about `Verify payment 123123` ?